# remote work - on which national laws the working contract will be based?

Tags: telecommute, legal, international

I've been looking for details about it but I could not find anything relevant.

Let's say I'm based in Belgium and I was able to find a remote work. The company is based in the US.

- The contract the company will give me, will be based on US' law or on Belgium law?
- If I feel there is a breach of contract, should I take the company to a Belgium court or an American one?

Comment: I think this is too close to situation-specific legal advice, which is off-topic here. Both questions will depend drastically on the type of work, type of contract and the countries involved.

Comment: i know for certain there are local laws that have to be obeyed in my country. They have this "nastly" laws that if I live here more than 6 months, I have to declare all my world wide proceedings, and if I have proceedings, I have to pay taxes and social security in the place where I work physically. Otherwise, it would be labeled as tax evasion. If you do not make them pay that taxes and register as your employer, you´d better factor them in your salary as they are coming out of your own pocket; in fact what I do believe is the latter being more common than the former when working remotely.

Comment: This is more a matter for a good accountant than a lawyer. He might advise you to open a firm, and register expenses to recoup some of the taxes.

Answer (score 3):

The contract will specify the jurisdiction where disputes will be settled.

You will want them to be local to you, they will want it to be local to them. If those desires are in conflict and if an agreement can't be reached, there will not be a contract.

If this isn't addressed in the contract then don't sign it.